# How to develop a cardview whose height must be responsive as per screen size

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have a cardview but its height is different in different mobile. How to fix the responsiveness issue across all the android devices.In case of setting min height wont help much in this case. Pls help me out here

PFB Xml code  i m using :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"
            >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            >
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/icons"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_background">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_dvr_white_48dp"
                    android:tint="#ffffff" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:text="Intro to Html"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icons"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subtitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:text="HTML Basics"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icons"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"

                />
</RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/main_layout"
            android:id="@+id/subtitle_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
                android:id="@+id/description"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                android:maxEms="4"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Role : Mutual Fund Planner "
                android:id="@+id/role"
                android:layout_below="@+id/description"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="12 min "
                android:id="@+id/duration"
                android:layout_below="@+id/role"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                />


        </RelativeLayout>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/subtitle_content"
                android:text="Begin Lesson"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: for that you have to fix the height of your layout.

Comment: You could do it programmatically by getting the screen's Width and Height. After that, you could assign for example the width of a Layout's Height = WidthOfScreen / 10. Or include all the above inside a ScrollView.

Comment: what is correct way of getting screen height in android  ?

Comment: cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        int mHeightScreen = display.getHeight();
        cardView.setMinimumHeight((int)(0.9)*mHeightScreen); this is also not helping

Comment: Do you have the AppCompat 23.2.0 or newer? It is neccessary nesting too much RelativeLayout?

Comment: no its not necessary to have too much RelativeLayout but we have support earlier version